# Ejecucion no esperada de setTimeout Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Para la siguiente instrucción:

```
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){  
     alert("Primero->"+i);

     setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Segundo->"+i);
      }, (i+1)*600);

}
```

La salida es la siguiente:

> Primero->0
>
> Primero->1
>
> Primero->2
>
> Segundo->3
>
> Segundo->3
>
> Segundo->3

Necesito usar el indice **i** en el alert.

No entiendo muy bien la ejecución de setTimeout, y porque espera a terminar el for para comenzar la ejecución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitarías pasarle una función como callback a tu función `setTimeout`. Algo similar a esto:

```js
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){
     alert("Primero->" + i);
     setTimeout(muestraValores, (i+1)*600, i);
}

function muestraValores(i){
  alert("Segundo->" + i);
}
```

Los parámetros se los deberías de pasar como tercer argumento para que el `setTimeout` respete el retardo al ejecutar la función.

Answer (score 4):

Este es un error conocido como Closure dentro de un loop, lo importante que hay que saber es que se produce cuando **creas una funcion dentro del ciclo for y utilizas en la funcion el iterador**

Hay varias formas de resolverlo. En ECMAScript 2015, puedes usar `let` en el `for` y funciona sin problemas (`let` por `var`)

```js
for(let i = 0; i<3; i++){  
     alert("Primero->"+i);

     setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Segundo->"+i);
     }, (i+1)*600);
}
```

Otra opcion es envolver la funcion creada en una IIFE (funcion auto ejecutable).

```js
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++){  
     alert("Primero->"+i);

     (function(i) { 
        setTimeout(function() {
           alert("Segundo->"+i);
        }, (i+1)*600) 
      })(i);
}
```

Finalmente, puedes como dice la respuesta de @Error404, utilizar una función **declarada fuera del for**

> Necesito usar el indice i en el alert.
>   No entiendo muy bien la ejecución de setTimeout, y porque espera a terminar el for para comenzar la ejecución.

El problema surje por la naturaleza de las variables `var` de javascript (una caracterista, no un bug). Estas variables "viven" en el ambito lexico de la funcion superior. Por eso se resuelve con `let` (que mueve al variable al ambito de la funcion local, en este caso el for) y con los otros metodos que crean una nueva funcion que oculta la varianble `i` original.